# Structured Data not indexing in a request made through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, seo

Google structured data tool is not indexing the content coming from an ajax file.

I've pages of several categories i.e. `vegetable.php`, `fruits.php` etc. and in every page, content is coming from an ajax file `ajax_loaddata.php` only.

Now that ajax file contains all the proper structured data markup but not getting indexed by Google or Bing.

How do I make this right?

Comment: … other than *not* using Ajax?

Comment: That works absolutely fine, can see in webmaster tools